# Incident with another cyclist, repair costs too expensive

Tags: damages, spain

Past week I had a bike incident with another cyclist. The rider in front of me slowed down and when I looked back to confirm no one was behind, he stopped and I hit him. Totally my fault, and no one get hurt. Typical mistake.

I gave my phone number to the other person and ask him if he wants to go to a bike shop at the moment but he refuse because it was late for him. Anyway, he contact me the day after asking for 370 euros for the repairs. I consider this amount of money ridiculous since the damage is only in the gear drive that is twisted (not broken).

At the moment I had some shots of the damage and a video of the person riding after with no problem apparently.

My question is if I should ask the person to take the bike to a shop repair that I trust and get a new budget for this? Or even buy the parts and install it by myself.

---

This is in Spain and I am not covered by insurance for this incident.

The person is very reluctant to detail the repairing. I told that I accept the costs and the repair shop but I need a detailed invoice. Somehow the pictures I took are helpful to clarify how damaged it was.

This was between two Bicycles. As additional info, we were not riding together.

[image]

Comment: This could be a topic for the Law stackexchange site. Which country is this? Do you have any sort of liability insurance? The money claimed from you should in any case be backed by recepts of some form.

Comment: I also think this is a legal question, best answered by Spanish experts, but it's great that you are asking for help and advice. It could be that 370 is a fair price, bikes can be expensive and so can labour, or it could be that someone is trying to get extra money out of your good nature. Not everyone would have done the decent thing like you are trying to do, so don't let someone take advantage. It won't hurt them to wait a short time while you decide how you want to proceed, and what money is fair. It is certainly in your interest to have the valuation done by someone you trust.

Comment: Definitely demand that he show you some credible documentation of the costs.

Comment: Offering to do repairs yourself is an absolute no. The other rider has no idea of your competency, and you have a motivation to make repairs as cheaply and quickly as possible. Similarly you cannot ask the rider to use a repair shop you specify. *They* are the injured party, it's *their* bike so they need to use a shop *they* thrust. However, you can ask for a description of what was broken, what work needs to be done, cost (both parts and labor hours) and dispute it if you disagree with it. You can ask a separate repair shop you trust to review the work and cost and provide you evidence.

Comment: I'm not sure about "gear drive"  suspect its the rear derailleur mech.  Such a cost might be reasonable if it was expensive DI2 wireless or duraace grade components, and cost included labour to fix it.  However if it was Tourney/low grade gear then something's very off.  Perhaps a spontaneous upgrade on his part.

Comment: @DanielRHicks and it would be reasonable to ask for the damaged parts too. (edit) not that tinny acera blob of chinese cheese and rust !

Comment: @Argenti Equally the OP has no idea what relationship they have with the bike shop they choose. The OP should get a price for the work from a bike shop he trusts, and discuss from there.

Comment: You also want to think about why the cyclist in front of you stopped. You haven't explained, and it could be a genuine reason, but if they didn't stop for a good reason, then you need to find out if that is legally your fault, or not, where you live. If other cyclist stopped for no good reason, the crash could be their fault, this is why you need a Spanish law expert

Comment: More prevalent in car fraud is a phenomenon known here as 'crash for cash', where a fraudulent driver will stop for no good reason, then claim against the insurance of the poor sucker who had no chance of avoiding crashing into the back of their car. I'm not suggesting that the other party has done this to you, but there are bad people in the world looking to rip you off

Comment: Ask for a detailed and itemized bill from the work-shop that repaired the bike before paying.

Comment: **I will migrate this to Law.SE**, but if it rests here for a while first then the question gets answers from cyclists first, which are a mostly-different population to legal-types.  Cross-SE inter-site pollination etc.  Applying the David Razor, if this question were about cars or boats or taxiing aeroplanes, it would still be coherent.  As such, there is only a minor relation to bicycles, and far more to Spanish road rules.

Comment: @Swifty I'm not sure where you're from, but as far as I'm aware the person in back is always at fault. If you couldn't stop in time, then you were following too close.  It doesn't matter if they had a good reason to stop.  The only time the person in front would be at fault would be if they reversed unnecessarily, which would be very hard to prove unless you had a dash cam.  Also, as per your earlier comment, it might be big deal for them to wait for the money if their bike is their primary method of transportation.

Comment: @Kibbee This is _exactly_ why it's important to ask the right question of the right people, us arguing about it doesn't advance the problem in the slightest. I'm not rising to it

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. As an update, the person is very reluctant to detail the repairing. I told that I accept the costs and the repair shop but I need a detailed invoice. Somehow the pictures I took are helpful to clarify how damage it was. @Criggie I´m also a motorbike rider and apologies for the misleading term. This was between to Bicycles.  As additional info, we were not riding together.

Comment: For that many euros, you could buy them a new bike at the same level of components. It is pretty basic from the photograph. Not sure about the damage of the frame and the availability of the derailleur hanger, but the derailleur itself is quite cheap https://www.amazon.es/Shimano-Acera-RD-M360-bicicleta-velocidades/dp/B0036XBIMC The work in the shop will be not much more than one hour.

Comment: @FrozenButcher Question has got about as many responses here as its going to get.  I'm now migrating it to the law.SE site.  Good luck with your issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Great job taking the photo at the time, it could end up saving you some money.

I can see an Acera rear derailleur(inexpensive), a seven speed freewheel (cheap), a rusty chain (poorly maintained), a bent derailleur hanger (possible damage) and a rear derailleur cable which is doing something slightly funny.

Focusing on the seven speed freewheel, we can tell that this is a budget bike. I would expect you could replace the whole bike for 370 euros. Labour charges will make up a large portion of a repair bill, but it does seem like an inflated price.

You absolutely *must* insist on transparency upfront from the bike owner. If they are not prepared to tell you what they want to spend your proposed 370 euros on, then I am confident they are trying to rip you off. If they tell you what the money will be spent on and you are struggling to decide if it is reasonable, please ask us about it with the updated info, before you pay any money at all.

Also seek some regional legal input into what your obligations and time frame need to be (we aren't lawyers!). If you meet your legal obligations and do so in a timely manner, then you are free to be as generous or not as you like in returning the bike to the condition it was in before the incident.

---

As for the original questions (sorry). I would suggest having the quote for the repairs approved by someone you trust in advance, yes perhaps a third party bike shop you trust. I would suggest not doing the repair work yourself. Even though that could be cheaper, you don't want any follow-ups from the other person. So if the repair is done at the other person's choice of repair shop, with your prior agreement about the cost and extent of the work, then they cannot follow up and ask you for more money after the fact.

Comment: I happened to check - an Acera grade rear mech in black is 16 euros brand new at CRC in Spain in late April 2020.   https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/es/en/shimano-acera-m360-7-8sp-rear-derailleur/rp-prod38673    OP is being gouged in costs.